# How to solve the system of equations like this one?

Tags: problem-solving

I have a hidden linear function: $f(x)=a*x+b$. For example $f(x)=2*x+3$

A hidden function $f$ was executed on some hidden input $x$=(0,1,3,4) and we have access only to output $y=(f(0)=3, f(1)=5, ...)=(3,5,9,13)$

How to find: $(a, b, \vec{x})$? In this case the correct answer is $(a=2, b=3, x=(0,1,3,4))$

There is possibility to construct the system of equations but I do not know how to solve them.
$$\begin{cases}
a*x_1+b=3,\\
a*x_2+b=5,\\
a*x_3+b=9,\\
a*x_4+b=13.\\
\end{cases}$$
The number of unknowns is greater than knowns, but we are limited to linear hidden functions only. Should I rewrite as matrix multiplication and use some sort of decomposition? Should I use Linear programming?

Note: there exists trivial solution $(a=1, b=0, x=y)$ I am interested in non trivial solutions and general approach for any $(a,b,x)$

Edit1: what are the possible restrictions to get unique solution? For example: $(a,b,x)$ natural numbers, maximize $(a, b)$ and minimise $(x)$,...

Comment: If you don't know $a$ and $b$, indeed the number of unknowns is greater than the number of equations and you can basically choose any solution that you want. You can for example always fix $a=1$ and $b=0$, which always gives you a trivial solution. Or do you have some restrictions for the relationships between $x_1, x_2 $ etc?

Comment: @MattiP. thank you for a nice comment. I am not interested in trivial solutions. I will update the question.

Comment: This question is missing some necessary information. What are $3,5,9,13$? I see that if $f(3)=9$ and $f(5)=13$, then $(a,b)=(2,3)$. But I'm just guessing here! And where does $(0,1,3,4)$ come from? Please tell us the whole story.

Comment: That's better! Now it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are infinitely many solutions. If $a \ne 0$, then we can always fix $(a,b)$ and then solve for $x_i$.

Assuming you are looking for non-negative integer solutions.

If $a=1$, then we can set $b \in \{1,2,3\}$ and then decide for $x_i$.

Now assume $a>1$,

$$a(x_2-x_1)=2$$

$$a(x_3-x_1)=6$$

$a$ is a common divisor of $2$ and $6$. $a=2$ and we can either pick $b$ to be $1$ or $3$ and then solve for corresponding $x_i$.

Possible restriction: Let $b$ to be as large as possible and all variables are nonnegative.

Comment: Is it possible to prove that following this approach and having this restriction we get unique solution?

Comment: with nonnegtive constraint and if we want to maximize $b$, then $b$ must take value $3$. Clearly $a \ne 0$, hence $x_1=0$. At this point it is still not unique. If we further impose the condition that $a>1$, then the solution is unique.

Answer (score 1):

The question, as originally posted, is unsolvable uniquely. You can imagine that easily, this way:
Suppose we try plotting $f(x)$ on the Cartesian plane. We have access to $4$ outputs, so we draw the lines:
$$y=3$$
$$y=5$$
$$y=9$$
$$y=13$$
We know that our function must intersect all $4$ lines. Now you can see the problem very clearly. Any line with a non-zero slope will certainly intersect all $4$ lines. So this much information is not enough to solve the question. Even if we were given the value of *a*, that is, the slope of the line, still we could create infinite parallel lines which would satisfy the given conditions. So it would still be unsolvable.

Comment: I see. Can you please suggest: what are the possible restrictions get unique solution? For example smallest non-negative integers...

Comment: That could be a possible restriction. But which variable do we want to be the smallest? I mean, the there are basically 6 unknowns to be found out. So on the set of real numbers solution can't be found without 6 equations. But if you look for solutions in some other set, say, natural numbers or integers, it could possibly be done.

Comment: For example: $(a,b,x)$ natural numbers, maximize $(a, b)$ and minimise $(x)$. Is it possible to find unique solution then?